# Use a variable to fill a field with Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, cucumber, gherkin

It is possible to use a variable to set a value using Selenium - Cucumber?

In my Class.Java :
I tried to create a private variable
( private String username = "x"; )

with Setter
( public void setUsername(String username).. )

But the value doesn't change when i use setUsername from another class.

```
MyClass myVariable = new MyClass ();
myVariable .setUsername("myUsername");
myVariable .setPassword("myPassword");
```

myVariable becomes "myUsername" but When " @Before " starts, the value is "x" even if I changed it.

The value of the variable must be dynamic and non-static for the purposes of the project.
Can i use Config.properties to do this ? There is a way to solve this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please include the Java code for the getter and setter.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for the answer. 
I solved this problem using data from Config.properties file.

I have another question for you: Can i start a cucumber test from another Java Project? 
I export my first Project (that contains MyClass.Java and MyClass.feature) but when i try to start MyClass.feature, it doesn't read MyClass.Java and advice me to add all the steps)

Answer (score 0):

`"myUsername"` is the literal string. If you want to pass the variable, it should be `myVariable.setUsername(username);` I guess from the code you provided.

Also, I if the space between `myVariable` and `.setUsername` is in your code it won't work.

Comment: Hi ou_ryperd, thank you for the answer. 
I solved this problem using data from Config.properties file.

I have another question for you: Can i start a cucumber test from another Java Project? 
I export my first Project (that contains MyClass.Java and MyClass.feature) but when i try to start MyClass.feature, it doesn't read MyClass.Java and advice me to add all the steps)